# Using Client_credential oauth grant good or bad?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-saml

I have a couple of APIs and building a web app which will use these APIs to load and update data in DB. I have configured OAuth server, API endpoints as OAuth resource server and web app as OAuth client.

I am playing around an idea of using SAML for authentication and OAuth for authorization to secure the API endpoints. But after lots of research and readings, I couldn't find anything for the same with spring.

Initially, I played around Auth_code grant, but it didn't work well with SAML authentication since OAuth Resource server needs the user to be authenticated as well. I am going to try implementing pre_auth_filter on OAuth server to see if it works with SAML authentication. But for the time being, I tried client_credentials grants for OAuth server. It works well. But is it a good approach from the security perspective to use the client_credentials grant for web app if OAuth client and server are running on the same network? Also if the web app is deployed on multiple servers can they share same client-id and secret?

Comment: Why do you want to implement saml AND oauth ? I think you need only one :
https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2013/05/09/choosing-an-sso-strategy-saml-vs-oauth2/

Comment: User authentication is managed by SAML Idp and API endpoints are to be secured with authorization workflow based off of authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common usage I have seen around is using Spring Security with Oauth 2.0 framework for authentication and authorization. In a complex environment, there would be a centralized auth server, responsible for authenticating all users and
all application services. In this scenario, recommend option for client services is to use `client_credentials` grant type to authenticate themselves. For RESTful services, Spring provides [OAuth2RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html) for this purpose.

Client credentials would be per application service not per application instance.

As we know the most common way of securing data in transit is to transmit data using TLS (SSL). Since all these web application services are on same network, you can make use of self signed certificates. Again, cert per service not per application instance. It goes without saying that for publicly exposed resources make use of certificate singed by a Certificate Authority.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am unable to upvote your answer due to lack of reputation. I am configuring OAuth Client on UI application itself. So if I have multiple instances of same UI app running on multiple servers that is the scenario I am considering in question.